# parent component accesses one of its child via ViewChild but it is always undefined

Tags: angular

I have a component with another one of my own components in its template:

```
<div (click)="onEditStarted()">
    ...
    <my-child *ngIf="someCondition"></my-child>
    ...
</div>
```

And in the parent I have:

```
@ViewChild(MyChildComponent) child: MyChildComponent;
```

But where I need `child`, it is `undefined`.

```
OnEditStarted() {
    ...
    setTimeout(() => this.child.someMethod(), 0);
   ...
}
```

I also tried to negate the `someCondition` and put it into the `[hidden]` property instead of `*ngIf` but it is still `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on v.6 and v.8 when I tried it. Please when you ask a question, **test and make sure** that your question and the code you are presenting actually reproduces the issue you are having, currently it does not. Please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz.

Comment: @AJT82 Thank you for your effort. I am currently on v7. Because the project is quite big, I will try my best to get an example of the excerpt up & running, or rather failing lol, on stackblitz.

Comment: @AJT82 Actually `my-child` is not the immediate child, will that matter to `@ViewChild`? The Angular document doesn't seem to mention this aspect.

Comment: Yes that would actually matter, if it's not the immediate child. Sounds to me, that you would want to communicate between components through a service :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in The *ngIf directive. It's killing the my-child component so it couldn't reference it. You can try using `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild` or try to wrap the ngIf using a `ng-template`

Comment: `*ngIf` was a concern to me so I tried `[hidden]` instead but no luck.